# Add untracked file to unstaged area in GIT

Tags: git

By default if I use `git add` , it directly adds the file to staged area.
I want it ,to add it to, unstaged area only. How to do that ?

Comment: There is no such thing. Modified just means "changed since it was last commited".

Comment: then don't use add

Comment: So, is there any way or there is not ?

Comment: why down vote ?

Comment: @Breaking Benjamin - what do you mean?  There's no such thing as "modified area".  A file can be "tracked" (add) or tracked and committed.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Please clarify.  See also the [git add documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

Comment: Please have a look here : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository. I agree we cannot say "area" . but modified state exists. I used the term bit loosely but not wrong. Here I edit the question to be precise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `git add -N <filename>`.

Comment: Worth noting (attaching this to the accepted answer): `git add -N` was rather badly broken before Git version 2.7.2, and there have been a bunch of more minor fixes since then.

Answer (score 10):

You might be looking for `--intent-to-add` option:

> **-N**, **--intent-to-add**
>
> Record only the fact that the path will be added later. An entry for the path is placed in the index with no content. This is useful for, among other things, showing the unstaged content of such files
>   with git diff and committing them with git commit `-a`.

This will add the file to index as an empty one, which will make `git diff` show all of its contents as "added".